# ¿Cómo accedo con flutter a una propiedad del propio Widget?

Tags: flutter

Tengo este código:

```
Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          height: 50,    
          width: 50,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.orange,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25)),
                   ),
```

Quiero que el argumento del método circular del Widget Radius sea la propiedad height del Container dividido entre 2. ¿Es posible hacer esta referencia?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear una variable de tipo `double` para manejar la altura y el `radius`:

```
double height= 50;
```

Y aquí únicamente asígnamos esta variable a la altura y al `borderRadius`:

```
    Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          height: height,    
          width: 50,
          // le quitamos el const, porque no va a ser un valor constante.
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.orange,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(height / 2)),
                   ),
```

Comment: Sí, eso lo sabía, pero solo quería saber si era posible acceder a ese valor sin una variable intermedia. Ok, gracias.